# Derive Delta (Greeks) using change of probability measure (Mathematical Finance)

Tags: probability, expected-value, martingales, finance

This question is not for homework, it is just for personal curiosity.

I am aware that we can calculate the greeks using basic calculus, and simplification. I am also aware that there is a great video by quantpie on youtube that uses a similar method to what I am trying to do.

Note: The greeks are the partial derivatives of the price of the european call option taken with respect to the parameters. I am concerned with $\Delta$ which is the partial derivative with respect to $S(0)$.

My goal: calculate $$\Delta=\partial C/\partial S(0)$$
using change of probability measure, where $$C=e^{-rT}\mathbb{E}[max(S(T)-K,0)]$$
where C is the price of the European call with the strike price K and expiration T. Also $$S(t)=S(0)e^{(r-0.5\sigma^{2})t+\sigma W(t)}$$

We know that there exists a measure Q such that C is a martingale. So we have,

$$C(0)=e^{-rt}\mathbb{E}_{Q}[max(S(t)-K,0) \mid \mathcal{F}_{0}]$$

where $\mathcal{F}_{0}$ is natural filtration with information at $t=0$. So we have

$$\frac{\partial C(0)}{\partial S(0)}=e^{-rt}\frac{\partial}{\partial S(0)}\mathbb{E}_{Q}[max(S(t)-K,0) \mid \mathcal{F}_{0}]$$
$$e^{-rt}\mathbb{E}_{Q}[\frac{\partial}{\partial S(0)} max(S(t)-K,0) \mid \mathcal{F}_{0}] \  (justification \ needed)$$
$$=e^{-rt}e^{(r-0.5\sigma^{2})t+\sigma W(t)}\mathbb{E}_{Q}[\mathbb{I}_{S(t)>K} \mid \mathcal{F}_{0}]$$
$$=e^{-rt}e^{(r-0.5\sigma^{2})t+\sigma W(t)}\mathbb{Q}[S(t)>K]$$

Note: C is martingale under $\mathbb{Q}-measure$

However, things aren't cancelling out very nicely. Ideally things would simplify to to
$$\frac{\partial C(0)}{\partial S(0)}=\mathbb{Q}[S(t)>K]$$
but this is not really working out. I appreciate any help or tips!

Comment: "calculate the greeks". Ummm... what are "the greeks"?

Comment: "the greeks"? what the hell is this?

Comment: @davidg.stork In mathematical finance the "Greeks" are partial derivatives of the value of a financial derivative.

Comment: @masacroso In mathematical finance the "Greeks" are partial derivatives of the value of a financial derivative.

Answer (score 1):

You have

$$C_0=e^{-rT}E^Qmax(S_T-K,0)=e^{-rT}E^Qmax(S_0e^{(r-0.5\sigma^2)T+\sigma W_T}-K,0)$$

Hence

$$\frac{\partial C_0}{\partial S_0}=e^{-rT}E^Q(I(S_T-K>0)e^{(r-0.5\sigma^2)T+\sigma W_T})=e^{-rT}E^Q(I(S_T-K>0)S_T/S_0),$$

where $I$ is the indicator (more formally heaviside) function. This term can be evaluated by noting that $S_T$ is log-normal. This describes the risk neutral expectation of the stock price conditional on hitting above $K$. In the Black-Scholes model this turns out to be of the form $N(d_1)$. The derivation is a bit tedious but very standard and can be found in textbooks covering the BS model.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am mainly having trouble seeing how we get $\partial C_{0}/\partial S_{0}=e^{-rT}E^{Q}[I(S_{T}>K)S_{T}/S_{0}]=N(d_{1})$. I know how to show $E^{Q}[I(S(T)>K)]=Q[S(T)>K]=N(d_{1})$, no problem with that. My problem is that $e^{-rt}S_{T}/S_{0}$ should simplify to 1.

Comment: The intuition is that the derivative of $max(S_0exp(z)-K,0)$ with respect to $S_0$ is $exp(z)$ when $(S_0exp(z)-K>0$ and zero otherwise.

Comment: In BS model $N(d_1)$ is not the probability of ending in the money $Q(S(T)>K) \neq N(d_1)$ (which is described by $N(d_2)$). $N(d_1)$ is related to the  expectation of the stock price conditional on being in the money.